# CKException Reason: The application is missing required entitlement com.apple.developer.icloud-services

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, icloud, visual-studio-app-center

I am developing a `Xamarin.Forms` application with iCloud data backup support for iOS. Everything works perfectly until I enabled `iCloud` support. I have done the following things to enable `iCloud` support.

Note: The `iCloud` support works perfectly on a simulator, the only problem with the phone.

**Download certificate and provision profile from `https://developer.apple.com/`**

1. Enabled the `iCloud` with Include `CloudKit` support (requires `Xcode 6`)
   option in app identifier.
2. Downloaded the new provision profile.

**Project**

1. Enabled the following items in Entitlement.plist

[image]

2. Accessed the iCloud container using the following code.

   `CKContainer.DefaultContainer.PrivateCloudDatabase`;

**App centre**

1. Uploaded the certificate and provision profile in release iPhone build.
   And finally, installed the app centre build on real iPhone device.

Could you please suggest me how to debug this exception?

SIGABRT: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: `CKException` Reason: The application is missing required entitlement `com.apple.developer.icloud-services` Native stack trace: `0 CoreFoundation 0x00000001a921ead0`

**Edit**

I have pushed the build from app center to testflight, but I am getting the following exception.

CKError 0x28114b960: "Network Failure" (4/NSURLErrorDomain:-1202); "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “gateway.icloud.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."

Comment: Hi , whehter use the same development provision profile when running in physical device?

Comment: Yes, I am using same provision profile.

Comment: Now I have pushed the same ipa file to testflight from appcenter, but I am getting the following exception when I launch app from testflgith.  SIGABRT: <CKError 0x28114b960: "Network Failure" (4/NSURLErrorDomain:-1202); "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “gateway.icloud.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."

Comment: Okey , you can have a try with enterprise provision file , because apple set the limitations of free developer provision file about the Supported capabilities (iOS). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos#limitations

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have also tried with distribution profile, but no luck.

Comment: Note: I am using provision profiles generated from paid developer account, not free one.